# ADO YAML task for Docker Container Image Creation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to find out what is the equivalent ADO YAML task for the Classic "Task group: Docker Container Image Creation".
I tried Docker and Docker Compose tasks but both of them don't have an argument to capture the environment the application package was built for.

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of the task in the classic editor is "***Task group:** Docker Container Image Creation*", what you see in the classic editor is probably a [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops):

> A task group allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already defined in a build or a release pipeline, into a single reusable task that can be added to a build or release pipeline, just like any other task. You can choose to extract the parameters from the encapsulated tasks as configuration variables, and abstract the rest of the task information.
> ...
>
> Task groups are a way to standardize and centrally manage deployment steps for all your applications. When you include a task group in your definitions, and then make a change centrally to the task group, the change is automatically reflected in all the definitions that use the task group. There is no need to change each one individually.

When a task group is created the creator can define their own parameters and use them in one or more subtasks inside the task group.

To replicate this behavior in yaml pipelines you need to examine the task group to understand what tasks it contains and then define a reusable [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) in yaml, which allows you to define reusable content, logic, and parameters

Answer (score 0):

Task group is only available classic pipelines (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops)).

[image]

For YAML pipelines, you can set up the [step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#step-reuse) to reuse the same steps in different YAML pipelines.